# iOS search bar added after a small delay doesn’t appear in the navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

If I add a search bar after a 0.1 second delay then it doesn’t appear in the navigation bar. If I change the delay to 0.5 seconds then it does appear. Is this because when the delay is short it runs during the push animation? How can I make it show up after the 0.1 second delay?

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    double delayInSeconds = .1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
        UISearchController *searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
        [self.navigationItem setSearchController:searchController];
        [self.navigationItem setHidesSearchBarWhenScrolling:NO];
    });
}
```

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya LOL :)

Comment: try definesPresentationContext to true like `self.definesPresentationContext = true`

Comment: Why you are adding it after delay ? is there any reason to do so ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I'm adding the search bar asynchronously. The delay is a shorthand way of expressing the problem

Comment: @grahammendick Any why you want to add it async. there would be no difference if you directly put it in view did load

Comment: I need to do an asynchronous check to decide whether or not to add it

Comment: Try to use MAIN Thread when you are adding Search bar. Generally, this code works for me `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:  DispatchTime.now() + 0.1, execute {// add your search bar here}`

Comment: My code sample does use the Main thread. The problem happens when the search bar is added in the pushed screen. Have you tried your code out in the pushed screen?

Answer (score 1):

put your code inside this block...it will delay 1 sec & let me know if any issue

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1, execute: {


        })
```

Comment: The problem happens when the search bar is added in the pushed screen. Have you tried your code out in the pushed screen?

Comment: i have tried this code to open collectionview after 1 sec delay...plz share your code..

Answer (score 1):

I've tried doing the same in my project, and it just doesn't work in `viewDidLoad` **consistently** even if I specify the delay to be 0.5 seconds

In my opinion, doing this in `viewDidLoad` is not a good idea(for this context), as the view of the VC that you push mostly gets loaded before the push animation even starts and the delay is complete before the animation completes

It ends up working fine for me in these cases:

- When preferred not to animate the push, i.e: `navigationController?.pushViewController(yourVC, animated: false)`
- When I animate the push and do all the delay stuff in the pushed VC's `viewDidAppear` (This is probably what you need to do)

Assigning the `navigationItem`'s `searchController` before the push animation completes is the culprit as far as I can see

Comment: Thanks for trying! I agree with your identification of the culprit but I'm looking for a solution, not a workaround. Isn't there some way to get the search bar to update during the push? It works OK for other navigation bar items like buttons, so why not the search bar?

Comment: Actually, the `navigationItem`'s `searchController` is assigned but the layout somehow doesn't get updated when the controller is set during animation no matter what I try. Clearly, something beyond our scope of reach doesn't let us/is probably buggy, which I wouldn't care much about. Doing this in `viewDidAppear` seems more like a solution than a workaround imo.

To answer your question, I think that the bar button items are more like `subviews` that probably won't be as complicated as `childViewControllers`

Comment: The search bar should appear as soon as it returns so that the animation's smooth, like with bar buttons. You've seen how jumpy it looks when you add it in `viewDidAppear`, right?

Answer (score 0):

This one work for me

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
        self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. The problem happens when the search bar is added asynchronously in the pushed screen. Have you tried your code out in the pushed screen?